# Removing buttons from a list

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to remove a button from a list and for some reason the function doesn't seem to be working correctly.  It seems to be some type of problem with the selector, because if I use the 'id' selector for the 'ul' it works just fine.  But when I change it to the class selector for the 'li' within the list it no longer works.  Does anyone have an idea what this might be?

Thanks in advance for your help with this.

```
$('#courses').append('<li class="plan" data-icon="delete"><a>'+in_course+' Credit: '+in_hrs+' Grade: '+ in_gpa+'</a></li>').listview('refresh');


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.plan').on('click',function() {
         $(this).parent().remove();
    }); });
```

Comment: If it's not working, what result ARE you getting? Your code above seems to state that when `li.plan` is clicked, its parent is removed; its parent being the `#courses` element

Comment: Have you confirmed via some form of debugging whether your selector is actually selecting something and if so what? Where is the line with the append being called? And perhaps you could put in the code with the ul referred to by ID to give us an idea of what you want to happen... there seems to be some confusion as to what behaviour is actually desired. :)

Comment: Another topic: Don't you need a list refresh after removal of link?

Comment: @priyeshj How and where would you go about doing this?

Comment: I really can't add comments with enter =/ .... $('.plan').on('click',function() { $(this).remove();
$('#courses').listview('refresh'); });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this works for you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.plan a').on('click',function() {
     $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.plan').on('click',function() {
     $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

Using your code will remove #courses

Answer (score 1):

Try changing that to:

```
$('#courses').on('click', '.plan', function () {
    // same code here
});
```

This is a *delegate event handler*, as opposed to the normal *bind event handler*. Delegates are normally used for elements with future elements, like the list item you're appending.

Also, make sure to put the `.append()` call chain inside the document ready handler, just in case you're not doing that.

Comment: This has the effect of removing the entire list.  I only want to delete a single 'li' element.